# Javascript Incrementing value in an array by value in JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a JSON object that contain a set of key:values. I want to first check if that first the key matches an array value and then if it does to add the value amount to that same buffers array within that array.

Here's my code to hopefully show what I mean:

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt){
 cities = JSON.parse(evt.data);
            for(var i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {                
                if(buffer[i][0] == cities.clusters) {
                    buffer[i][1][0]++;
                }
            console.log(buffer);
            }
       };
```

This is my buffer array:

```
var buffer = [['1',[0]],['2',[0]],['3',[0]],['4',[0]]];
```

This is the JSON output received from the server:

```
{"clusters": {"London": 4, "Atlanta": 5}, "time": "2012-11-22 19:56:25"}
```

So what I want is that the buffer array on this iteration becomes:

```
 var buffer = [['London',[4]],['New York',[0]],['Atlanta',[5]],['LA',[0]]];
```

At every iteration these amounts then get added to and updated.

I don't know how to do this and I don't think the for loop will be able to do it.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to do it and the above for loop won't do it.

Comment: For one, `cities.types` doesn't even exist; the server doesn't return that field.

Comment: Thanks....been a 14hour session today, brains half asleep.

Comment: where do the values `New York` & `LA` come from??

Comment: These exist in the buffer array and I'll first try to match cities.clusters to these in the buffer array.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you seem to be assuming that the 1 in the buffer array will always be associated with the London, 2 with New York etc.  But you aren't guaranteed that the object's properties will come out in the same order every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to pretend that your buffer is this:

```
var buffer = [['London',[0]],['New York',[0]],['Atlanta',[0]],['LA',[0]]];
```

Then the loop becomes this:

```
for (var i = 0, item; item = buffer[i]; ++i) {
    buffer[i][1][0] = cities.clusters[item[0]] || 0;
}
```

The expression `cities.clusters[item[0]] || 0` uses the value of the respective city or `0` if not defined.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/uyisab/1/)

Comment: Thanks that works! So in this for loop are we saying that everytime theres a match in the buffer array of a city, add the current amount from the clusters value to the buffer array?

Comment: @user1869421 It replaces the value actually, but since you cannot have multiple occurrences of the same city inside your `cities.clusters` hash, that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the comments & edits, this should help : ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Bzy9/))

```
var data = {} ; // From Webservice

var buffer = [['London',[4]],['New York',[0]],['Atlanta',[5]],['LA',[0]]];

var clusters = data.clusters;

for (var i in clusters) for(var j in buffer) 

     if(buffer[j][i])  buffer[j][i] = cluster[i];
```